# How to copy few rows and insert copied cells -macro code

Tags: vba

New to macro, I need a code to copy few rows and insert copied cells on the same sheet,  to several rows below

---

Maybe I didn't explain myself right 
The inserted copied rows need to push row 11,12,and 13 (3 rows and insert copied rows) not replacing 
Cheers  Silver

---

We nearly there, I need the inserted copied rows need to push row 10-13 accordingly, i.e each row below 10 need to have the inserted copied rows
Cheers Silver

Comment: I've changed my answer. Is it what you need?

Comment: Try my new answer. P.S. you can write you comments in the _comment box_, instead of editing your question. It would be easier to detect your comments for me.

Comment: Found a mistake and updated answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, I've guessed what you need:)

```
Sub Test()
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim height As Integer
   Dim startRowToPaste As Integer
   Dim countOfPaste As Integer
   Dim startIndex As Integer

   Set rng = Range("3:6")
   height = rng.Rows.Count
   startRowToPaste = 7 ' num of first row at witch need to paste
   countOfPaste = 8 ' count of times you want to paste

   For i = startRowToPaste To startRowToPaste + countOfPaste - 1
       'determining num of row where need to paste values
       startIndex = startRowToPaste + (i - startRowToPaste) * (height + 1) + 1
       'insert new rows
       Rows(startIndex & ":" & startIndex + height - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
       'paste values
       rng.Copy Destination:=Range(startIndex & ":" & startIndex + height - 1)
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there away I can load a excel file to show you before and after scenario

Comment: Thanks for that
Here are the file before https://www.dropbox.com/s/cggknxscb23bkf8/GOLF%20IL%201%20macro.csv

And after 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8qjrllk2wj7u0y/GOLF%20IL%201%20macro%20after.csv

cheers

Comment: I've found the solution for your files and updated my answer:)

Comment: Hi simoco
Thanks for the great code, it does exactly what I need
I have a car recycling yard located in the UK(Wakefield) should you need a vehicle parts let me know, My email is in cell BE, will be happy to return good gesture 
Silver

Comment: You are welcome:) if you found my answer helpful, pleace mark it as correct answer)